# Angular $apply does not update the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have a form, when I submit it, it pushes some object to my array. Beneath that form I have a table that shows all items in that array. I want my table to update automatically (without refreshing the page) when new item pushed.

Submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateTable()">Pay</button>
```

In my controller:

```
  $scope.updateTable = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $scope.$apply();
      $scope.$digest();
    }, 0);
  };
```

However, it does not work.
I tried different approaches like $watch service, but i`ve got the same result.

Table

```
<div class="row paytable">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    {{payments.length}}
    <table class="table table-hover ">
      <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Cause</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in payments">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cause}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('mainController', [ 'user', '$rootScope', '$scope', 'payment', '$timeout', function(user, $rootScope, $scope, payment, $timeout) {

  user.getUsers();
  user.newUser();
  $rootScope.currentUser = user.currentUser();

  $scope.payments = payment.getPayments();
  $scope.newPayment = payment.newPayment;

  $scope.updateTable = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('apply ------------');
      $scope.$apply();
      $scope.$digest();
    }, 0);

  };

  $scope.showPayMessage = function() {
    console.log('im here');
    $scope.showSM = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.showSM = false;
    }, 2000);
  };
}]);
```

payment - my service for array manipulation.

Form

```
<div class="newpay row" >
  <div class=" col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <h1>Hello, {{currentUser.name}}</h1>
    <h4 ng-show="showSM" class="bg-success">Payment confirmed</h4>
    <form name="inputform" ng-submit="newPayment(amount, cause); showPayMessage();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Amount</label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="amount" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Amount" required>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Cause</label>
        <input type="text" name="cause" ng-model="cause" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Cause" required>

      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateTable()">Pay</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
payments: {{payments.length}}
<payments-table payments="payments"></payments-table>
```

To display that table I created directive.

Comment: can you show the table code? (html and controller)

Comment: I can put that project into git repository if it`s not enough.

Comment: It works fine, but does not update automatically, i have to refresh the page.

Comment: `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.$digest` are not needed but we'll get to it later. I don't see in your code a place for pushing new items to the `payment` array. The only way to get an updated table is to refresh and get it from the server. Am I correct?

Comment: There is no back-end part in my app. I created 'payment' service to deal with array. Array passes to localStorage in that service. I`ll put my project to github in a minute.

Comment: Your `payments` array is populated once, in the controller constructor. You have to call your service again, after submitting, and get the updated array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118736/discussion-between-arans-and-arthur-kishinets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.$apply` and `$scope.$digest` are better suited for working with 3rd party libraries or testing. In your case Angular is well aware to your changes. The thing is, your `payments` array, that resides in a service should be queried again after submitting a new item (unless you have a direct reference to the array, then no query should be made).

Like this:

**View**

```
<form name="inputform" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.onSubmit = function() {
    newPayment($scope.newItemAmount, $scope.newItemCause); // Assuming they are properties in the controller
    showPayMessage();
    $scope.payments = payment.getPayments(); // getting the updated array
}
```

Comment: You saved me again. Thank you. I thought, that in my controller i had a pointer to my array and it was passed by reference. Is there any way to pass array from the service by reference so I don`t need to reassign scope property every time?

Comment: Let's see the service code, basically you should be able to hold a reference